# Get repository languages with the GitLab API

Tags: repository, gitlab, libraries, github-linguist

I would like to know if there is a way to get the languages (percentage per language) used in a project by using the API provided by GitLab. I checked their documentation but I didn't see anything about that or maybe I missed it.

I know that they use the Linguist [library](https://github.com/github/linguist) but I'm developping an application that's is not in Ruby and I'm looking for a way to integrate theses percentages.

Answer (score 12):

As of 10.8.x, Gitlab added a new API entrypoint, exposing languages used in a specific repository.

Usage is straight forward :

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <__ACCESS_TOKEN__>" https://gitlab.mydomain.com/api/v4/projects/<ID>/languages`

docs : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#languages

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there's no endpoint to do this right now as the data for language repartition is sent in inline javascript. But it might become available as they refactor the code (see [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28976) and [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27264))

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for the answer and the links to the issues. I hope it will be available soon...

Comment: Feel free to accept and/or upvote the answer if it answered your question https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234